# Display image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know why this code is not displaying any image when I run it.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
images = os.listdir()
i = 0
for images in images:
    if images.endswith(".png"):
        photo = PhotoImage(file=images)
        label = Label(image=photo)
        label.pack()
        print("reached here")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Presumably you are getting "reached here" messages?

Comment: yes I am getting reached here messages but it is not displaying the image

Comment: can u tell why it is not displayng the image??

Comment: This could be becuase image is "grabage collected", can you try, `label.image=photo` to keep a reference and let me know?

Comment: so what should I do to avoid this

Comment: ive updated my comment and have you installed the `PIL` library?

Comment: I think that what's happening is that references created by `PhotoImage` are temporary and will get destroyed before `root.mainloop()` is run. You need to create permanent references like `photo_1.image = photo`. Since you have multiple files I'd suggest using a dictionary to store all the permanent references.

Comment: I noticed that garbage collect problem.   Create a list for displayed images and save them.  Never mind, I'll make an answer...

Comment: I request you to please upvote the question as StackOverflow is not allowing me to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need to have `PIL` installed

```
pip install PIL
```

then

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
images = os.listdir()
imglist = [x for x in images if x.lower().endswith(".jpg")]

for index, image in enumerate(imglist): #looping through the imagelist
    photo_file = Image.open(image) 
    photo_file = photo_file.resize((150, 150),Image.ANTIALIAS) #resizing the image
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_file) #creating an image instance
    label = Label(image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.grid(row=0, column=index) #giving different column value over each iteration
    print("reached here with "+image)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to use `pack()` manager, then change

```
for image in imglist:
    ....... #same code as before but grid() to 
    label.pack()
```

Do let me know if any errors or doubts

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I played a little and got some results.  You can refine it:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
images = os.listdir()
imglist = [x for x in images if x.lower().endswith(".png")]
i = 0
photolist = []
labellist= []
for image in imglist:
    photo = PhotoImage(file=image)
    photolist.append(photo)
    label = Label(image=photo)
    labellist.append(label)
    label.pack()
    print("reached here with "+image)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I actually think `labellist` is not necessary and why is `i=0` used?

Comment: Oh so you have tried to use list comprehension...but still it is showing one image not multiple images

Comment: @Vasu This might be because your images are bigger sized?

Comment: Try saying this to see if the code actually works `for index,image in enumerate(imglist):` and then change `label.grid(row=0,column=index)`. I could also add an answer with the resize, if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220337/discussion-between-vasu-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: ive added an answer

Comment: but if we will use label.pack(), then it will also work as the images are resized

Comment: @Vasu yes sure, why not

Comment: I request you to please upvote the question as StackOverflow is not allowing me to ask more questions.